# How to create a User via django-allauth social login

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-socialauth

I have problems making actual User instance when using django-allauth.

I let users to login with other SNS account, and then It creates sociall accounts, not User instance on server.

And this 'all-auth' is also a problem. I read many lines of official docs and code but I can't even guess how it works.

```
{% load socialaccount %}
<ul>

    {% for provider in providers %}
        <li>
            {% if provider.social_app %}
            <a href="{% provider_login_url provider.id %}">{{provider.name}}</a>
            {% else %}
            <a>Provider {{ provider.name }} is not ready yet</a>
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

It's all I typed. (beside starting setups).
I click that provider_login_url, it goes to social login, my social account is authorized and I get logged in to may service.

I want to know how it works internally.
And how to make User instance that I can see and manage on my admin page.

Comment: look at https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/24/how-to-add-social-login-to-django.html

Comment: @lshwar well... I am using django-allauth and wanna keep it. but thx